# How to keep track of a score -- C++ Console

Tags: c++, console

I am making a poker game in C++ for a my intro to C++ class (should tell you that I am only a beginner so please excuse any bad programmer practice here). I am currently working on the betting system, in which I am quite pleased it does what I need it to do. Except that it doesn't carry on - the game just resets after the hand. Here's my code, I was thinking I need to make separate classes and then call those classes in the main, but I'm just not sure how that would be any different, if that's the case then I'll delete this question.

```
{// ConsoleApplication71.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Bet.h"
using namespace std; 

//Bet P = int betP(int money);

int main()
{
bool win;
bool lose;
int Omoney = 100;
int money = 0;
int Tmoney = 0;
int bet = 0;
int earn = (bet * 2) + Omoney;

int loseM = 0;
loseM = loseM + bet;


cout << "Your start money = " << Omoney << " \n\n\n" << endl;
cout << "Place your bet here!" << endl;
cin >> bet;

money = Omoney - bet;
cout << "Your total money after bet is " << money << "\n\n";


//betP(int money)
//{
//  money - bet = money;
//}
if (bet > 10)
{
    win = true;
    if (win = true)
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN! \n\n" << endl;
        /*earn = (earn) + Omoney;*/
        cout << "You earned: \n" << earn;
        Tmoney = earn + (Omoney - bet);
        cout << "\nTotal money: \n" << Tmoney;
    }
}
else if (bet <= 10)
{
    lose = true;
    if (lose = true)
    {
        cout << "You Lose!\n\n\n" << endl;
        int Mlose= loseM + bet;
        cout << "You lost: \n" << Mlose;
        Tmoney = loseM + (Omoney - bet);
        cout << "\nTotal money: \n" << Tmoney;
        cout << "\n\n\n\n";
        Omoney = Tmoney;
        main();
    }
}


cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aught to be using a loop, instead of recursively calling `main()` again.

Comment: if (win = true) I think you want to check it something here. use the equals operator if (win == true) or if (win)

Comment: In fact, calling `main` directly is prohibited by the language.

Comment: this question is more appropriate in codereview.stackexchange.com 

Comment: I'm not going to read your code, but I'll give you just one tip: _Always_ initialize all your variables when you create them.

Comment: First issue: can't call main. Second issue: you're not comparing in your if-statement, you're assigning. Use == instead of =.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop instead of calling `main()` again. When you call `main()`, the local variables are re-initialized.

Alternatively, make the variables global scope (declare them outside of main()).

Comment: And since calling `main` breaks the space time continuum.

Comment: I've never seen anyone call main() rec. before :)... Prolly bad for readability? Anyhow, please mark as answer if it helped. Thank you.

Comment: I can not mark the answer as helped yet because 7 minutes has not gone by yet, but as soon as it does I will. Also thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: @Eeeearth do not move variables to global scope. Do not call `main` recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Read from user "start money" before the loop, and then inside the loop read the bet and do something with the bet. I guess the loop should repeat reading the bets until the user runs out of money.